# StaggeredGridView set width and height for certain image

Tags: android, android-layout

Would like to create a layout where the top image is having a big size in a column, and those at the bottom are just nicely fit in 2 columns (looks alike GridView, all are scaled to same size). Is it possible to achieve this with StaggeredGridView? Is there any documentation for StaggeredGridView or guide for referring?

Comment: Refer to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type